# How to pass textviews from multiple activities to single activity?

Tags: android, data-structures, textview

I am new to android,
I have made an app which collects service request from customers.
The issue I am facing is on final page.
Suppose if i select service from page "service1" and proceed to final page and then backpressed to main page and select service from "service2" and proceed to final page then it is showing data from both "service1" and "service2".
I want to display either servicetype and textview which belongs to "service1" OR servicetype1 and textview1 which belongs to "service2" on final page based on selected service by customer.

My codes are as follows
Main Page

```
     Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
            

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openservice1();
            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openservice2();
            }
        });
              
    }

    public void opendryclean() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, service1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void opencarwash() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, service2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Service 1

```
 Spinner spinner;
    TextView textView;
    private Button button;
    
    private static String value1;
    public static String getValue1(){
        return value1;
    }
    private static String value2;
    public static String getValue2(){
        return value2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_service1);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        ArrayList<String> servList = new ArrayList<>();
        servList.add("type 1");
        servList.add("type 2");
        servList.add("type 3");
        servList.add("type 4");

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (i == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please Select service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    textView.setText("");
                }
                 else {
                  
                    textView.setText("xyz");
                      }
            }
               button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
               button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    value1 = (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    value2 = (textView.getText().toString().trim());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(service1.this, finalpage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        });
    }

    }
```

service 2

```
Spinner spinner;
TextView textView;
private Button button;

private static String value1;
public static String getValue1(){
    return value1;
}
private static String value2;
public static String getValue2(){
    return value2;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_service2);
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView16);
    ArrayList<String> servList = new ArrayList<>();
    servList.add("type 1");
    servList.add("type 2");
    servList.add("type 3");
    servList.add("type 4");

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (i == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please Select service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textView.setText("");
            }
             else {
              
                textView.setText("xyz");
                  }
        }
           button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
           button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                value1 = (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                value2 = (textView.getText().toString().trim());
                Intent intent = new Intent(service2.this, finalpage.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

Final Page

```
  TextView servicetype, textview, servicetype1, textview1;
    
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
    private Button button;
    DatabaseReference reff;
    Customer customer;

    EditText nameInput;
    EditText emailInput;
    EditText addressInput;
    EditText numberInput;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_finalpage);

        servicetype = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView30);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView31);
        servicetype1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView32);
        textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView33);

        servicetype.setText(service1.getValue1());
        textview.setText(service1.getValue2());
        servicetype1.setText(service2.getValue1());
        textview1.setText(service2.getValue2());

        nameInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        emailInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextEmailAddress);
        addressInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPostalAddress);
        numberInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
        customer = new Customer();
        reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Customer");

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                customer.setName(nameInput.getText().toString().trim());
                customer.setAddress(addressInput.getText().toString().trim());
                customer.setEmail(emailInput.getText().toString().trim());
                customer.setNumber(numberInput.getText().toString().trim());
                customer.setService(servicetype.getText().toString().trim());
                customer.settext(textview.getText().toString().trim());
                customer.setService1(servicetype1.getText().toString().trim());
                customer.settext1(textview1.getText().toString().trim());
                reff.push().setValue(customer);
                openconfirmation();
            }
        });
    }


    public void openconfirmation() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, confirmation.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have two buttons on the main screen. On the final screen, you want to show data pertaining to which button the user clicked. If the two options are largely similar, you can include the differing data in your Intent and parse it in your final Activity.

Comment: I have used the alternative method which is 'transferring data from one activity to another without using intent'.

Comment: Another thing is I don't want to use servicetype1 and textview1 in the final page. Just a single place that is "servicetype" and "textview" for fetching data from both services (1&2).